# Is there a way to update the matplotlib plot without closing the window?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm completely new to matplotlib and decently experienced but rusty with python and I'm struggling to work with matplotlib currently.
I'm trying to kind of animate a point on the plot, kind of like this:
https://www.desmos.com/calculator/rv8gbimhon

I've written the code for it but the plot doesn't update the point in real time during the while loop, instead, the while loop is paused until I close the plot window and the next iteration of the loop happens, re-opening the plot with the updated coords. Is there a way to move a point on matplotlib without opening and closing windows?

My code:

```
import numpy as np
import time
t = 0
start_time = time.time()
while t < 30:
    end_time = time.time()
    t = end_time - start_time
    print(t)
    plt.plot(t,t,"g^")
    plt.show()
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One option to update the plot in a loop is to turn on [interactive mode](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.ion.html#matplotlib.pyplot.ion) and to update the plot using [pause](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.pause.html#matplotlib.pyplot.pause).

For example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import time

point = plt.plot(0, 0, "g^")[0]
plt.ylim(0, 5)
plt.xlim(0, 5)
plt.ion()
plt.show()

start_time = time.time()
t = 0
while t < 4:
    end_time = time.time()
    t = end_time - start_time
    print(t)
    point.set_data(t, t)
    plt.pause(1e-10)
```

However, for more advanced animation I would propose to use the [animation class](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/animation_api.html?highlight=animate).