# Create Interactive / Animated Graph from 2D arrays in Python

Tags: python, numpy, graph, dynamic

I need your help.
I want to make a graph based on 2D arrays that ive generated. So i have an array which has space dimension and time dimension. I want to plot the space dimension array for every time step and make an animation of it if it possible.

Here is my code that i've done so far:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

i = 10 #time-step
j = 20 #space-step

z = np.random.rand(i,j) #2D space-time array 
x = np.arange(0, j, 1) #space axis


plt.figure()
plt.plot(x,z[0,:], '.') #plotting space axis at time-step = 0
```

output:

[image: output]

but this output only for z[0,:] array. I want to make also the z[1,:], z[2,:], and so on in same graph animatedly . Is it possible? or does anyone can help me to give an example?
thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Hi [@Kelana](https://stackoverflow.com/users/20485763/kelana), I update the answer with a snippet based on [Matplotlib animations](https://matplotlib.org/2.0.2/examples/animation/simple_anim.html).

## `matplolib.plt` (quick-and-dirty)

The code below (adapted from [question #66943917](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66943917/is-there-a-way-to-update-the-matplotlib-plot-without-closing-the-window)) allows you to update the plot in a loop, without closing the figure.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

i = 10 # time-step
j = 20 # space-step

z = np.random.rand(i,j)     # 2D space-time array 
x = np.arange(0, j, 1)      # space axis

fig = plt.figure()

# Turn out the interactive mode (allows to exploit `plt.pause` to refresh)
plt.ion()
# Plot animation loop   
for i in range(z.shape[0]):
    plt.clf()   # clear the plot without closing the window
                # NOTE. Remove if you want data to accumulate in the plot, step after step
    # Set axis limits and ticks
    x_unit = 1      # here for the sake of clarity, should go outside the loop
    plt.xlim(0 - x_unit, j + x_unit)    # points at the boundary of the domain can be seen entirely
    plt.xticks(list(np.linspace(0, j, num = j/2 + 1, endpoint = True)))
    y_unit = 0.1    # here for the sake of clarity, should go outside the loop
    plt.ylim(0.0 - 0.1 , 1 + 0.1)       # points at the boundary of the domain can be seen entirely
    plt.yticks(np.linspace(0, 1, num = 10+1, endpoint = True))
    # Refresh the plot
    plt.plot(x, z[i,:], '.') # plotting space axis at time-step i
    plt.title('Timestep {}'.format(i + 1))
    plt.show()
    plt.pause(1) # how long you want each time-step to stay
    # Save images to recreate the animation offline
    # NOTE. You have to create the `plots` folder manually
    #plt.savefig('./plots/timestep_{}.png'.format(i + 1))
```

[Click here for a preview of the animation result,](https://i.stack.imgur.com/srsYs.gif) unfortunately StackOverflow does not allow me to embed images in answers yet.

You can see that the code is not very efficient (you have to re-draw the image from scratch at each iteration), and the best way I found to save the animation is to export them individually and then merge them with an online GIF maker.

## `matplotlib.animation`

The following snippet allows to draw and save an animation in Matplotlib. The code is adapted from [here](https://jakevdp.github.io/blog/2012/08/18/matplotlib-animation-tutorial/).

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import animation

i = 10 # time-step
j = 20 # space-step

z = np.random.rand(i, j)     # 2D space-time array 
x = np.arange(0, j, 1)      # space axis

fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes(xlim = (0 - 1, j + 1),
              ylim = (0.0 - 0.1, 1 + 0.1),
              xticks = np.linspace(0, j, num = j/2 + 1, endpoint = True),
              yticks = np.linspace(0, 1, num = 10+1, endpoint = True)
              )

pts, = ax.plot([], [], '.')

def init():
    pts.set_data([], [])
    return pts,

def animate(i):
    # Refresh the plot
    ax.set_title("Timestamp #{}".format(i + 1))
    pts.set_data(x, z[i,:]) # plotting space axis at time-step i
    return pts,

# Set animation speed and duration
frame_dt = 2.0 #[s] 
frames_n = z.shape[0]

# Create and save animation
anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, init_func=init,
                               frames = frames_n, 
                               interval = int(1000 / frame_dt),  #[ms] 
                               blit = False
                               )
anim.save('basic_animation.mp4', fps = 1 / frame_dt, extra_args=['-vcodec', 'libx264'])
```

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t8NcU.gif) you have a sample of the output. I had to convert it to a GIF to be able to upload it on StackOverflow, please note that the animation is exported as an mp4 file.

Comment: Thanks @Luca . That is exactly what i meant. However, ur method is to extract the graph one by one then join it together become 1 gif. Is there any code to make it animation ?

Comment: I updated the previous answer to directly show/export an animation from code.